# Signed transaction vanishing from testnet (Kovan & Rinkeby)

Tags: ethereum

I've been attempting to broadcast transactions to both Kovan & Rinkeby, I'm building and signing them offline and using the Etherscan API to broadcast the signed transactions. I see them in the explorer labelled as:

*Pending This TxHash was found in our secondary node and should be picked up by our indexer in a short while.*

They sit there for between 4-8 hours then just vanish. I've tried increasing the gas price and gas limit a few times. And I'm assuming because they get accepted by the API at all I've correctly signed them (I'm using an external method to sign the hash and stitch together the transactions). I'm not sure if there's a way to validate the transaction to see if the one I've created is valid and properly signed.

The most recent one I've tried to broadcast to Kovan is:

```
f86d01850ba43b7400830186a0944d6bb4ed029b33cf25d0810b029bd8b1a6bcab7b88015181ff25a980008077a060023895819271c2b033820c913c9c6326325dbea272b09429d886833d5a900ca04ccf4a6a3710806b2d137f4460551a8a2ef6627b1da81fbd971c4a18aba8a880
```

I've tried to decode it with https://flightwallet.org/decode-eth-tx/ and it seems to look good.

```
{
  "nonce": 1,
  "gasPrice": 50000000000,
  "gasLimit": 100000,
  "to": "0x4d6bb4ed029b33cf25d0810b029bd8b1a6bcab7b",
  "value": 95000000000000000,
  "data": "",
  "from": "0xe6652ca72b030b1c426b3e9654bd02e466943d54",
  "r": "60023895819271c2b033820c913c9c6326325dbea272b09429d886833d5a900c",
  "v": "77",
  "s": "4ccf4a6a3710806b2d137f4460551a8a2ef6627b1da81fbd971c4a18aba8a880"
}
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone had some advice or tools I could use to debug this, or sees something incorrect in my encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `nonce` is too high, at least for that transaction. The from address, `0xE6652CA72B030B1c426b3e9654bd02E466943D54`, has sent no prior transactions, so its correct `nonce` is `0`.

Trying to send a transaction with `nonce` `1` means it has to wait around until a transaction with `nonce` `0` has been sent. If that doesn't happen, the transaction eventually just gets dropped.

A good way to get the correct `nonce` is to use `web3.eth.getTransactionCount()`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I thought I could just start at 1 for the first transaction, the flightwallet.org decoder was showing null when I used 0, this confused and threw me off the correct path.